# gradient descent cost convergence

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, gradient-descent

I have a small script that has the cost converge to zero for data sets xa and ya, but no matter what values I use for 'iterations' and 'learning_rate', the best cost I can get to is 31.604 when using data sets xb and yb.

My question is this:  Should cost *always* tend towards zero?  If yes, then what am I doing wrong with regards to data sets xb and yb?

```
import numpy as np


def gradient_descent(x, y):
    m_curr = b_curr = 0
    iterations = 1250
    n = len(x)
    learning_rate = 0.08

    for i in range(iterations):
        y_predicted = (m_curr * x) + b_curr
        cost = (1/n) * sum([val**2 for val in (y - y_predicted)])
        m_der = -(2/n) * sum(x * (y - y_predicted))
        b_der = -(2/n) * sum(y - y_predicted)
        m_curr = m_curr - (learning_rate * m_der)
        b_curr = b_curr - (learning_rate * b_der)
        print('m {}, b {}, cost {}, iteration {}'.format(m_curr, b_curr, cost, i))


xa = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
ya = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13])

# xb = np.array([92, 56, 88, 70, 80, 49, 65, 35, 66, 67])
# yb = np.array([98, 68, 81, 80, 83, 52, 66, 30, 68, 73])

gradient_descent(xa, ya)

# gradient_descent(xb, yb)
```

With xa and ya (using the values for iterations and learning_rate as shown above):

```
m 2.000000000000002, b 2.999999999999995, cost 1.0255191767873153e-29, iteration 1245
m 2.000000000000001, b 2.9999999999999947, cost 1.0255191767873153e-29, iteration 1246
m 2.000000000000002, b 2.999999999999995, cost 1.0255191767873153e-29, iteration 1247
m 2.000000000000001, b 2.9999999999999947, cost 1.0255191767873153e-29, iteration 1248
m 2.000000000000002, b 2.999999999999995, cost 1.0255191767873153e-29, iteration 1249
```

With xb and yb (iterations =  1000 and learning_rate = 0.00001):

```
m 1.0445229983270568, b 0.01691112775956422, cost 31.811378572605147, iteration 995
m 1.0445229675787642, b 0.01691330681124408, cost 31.81137809768319, iteration 996
m 1.044522936830507, b 0.016915485860422623, cost 31.811377622762304, iteration 997
m 1.044522906082285, b 0.016917664907099856, cost 31.811377147842503, iteration 998
m 1.0445228753340983, b 0.01691984395127578, cost 31.811376672923775, iteration 999
```

With xb and yb (iterations =  200000 and learning_rate = 0.00021):

```
m 1.017952329085966, b 1.8999054866690825, cost 31.604524796644444, iteration 199995
m 1.0179523238769337, b 1.8999058558198456, cost 31.60452479599536, iteration 199996
m 1.0179523186680224, b 1.89990622496171, cost 31.604524795346318, iteration 199997
m 1.017952313459241, b 1.899906594094676, cost 31.60452479469731, iteration 199998
m 1.017952308250581, b 1.8999069632187437, cost 31.604524794048356, iteration 199999
```

Comment: The gradient descent function will always tend to move towards the local minima. You are solving equation y=mx+b. In your xa, ya data, it was able to calculate closely with error ~0 (or) balance both sides of the equation. But in xb, yb case it is only able to solve with the error of ~31. The cost is nothing but the error the gradient descent finds while balancing the equation. Manually try calculating both sides of the equation, it will become clear.

Comment: Also, you can predict y with the x values with the average error of 0 for xa, ya data... And with average error of 31 for xb, yb data.

Comment: Ah...  Thank you.  So my understanding was just lacking.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy that it helped you understand. Consolidating the comment as answer to this question.

The gradient descent function will always tend to move towards the local/global minima. That is minimizing error/cost for successfully calculating the output(Y) with the provided input values(X) here.

> You are solving equation y=mx+b.

In your xa, ya data, it was able to calculate closely with error ~ 0 (or) balance both sides of the equation. 
But in xb, yb case it is only able to solve with the error of ~31.

```
The cost is nothing but the mean error the gradient descent finds while balancing the equation. 
Manually try calculating both sides of the equation, it will become clear.
```

Also, you can predict y with the x values with the average error of 0 for xa, ya data... And with average error of 31 for xb, yb data.